# NavigationDrawer fragment toolbar icons disappearing randomly

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar, navigation-drawer

I have an app with a **NavigationDrawer** and a number of fragments. The problem I now have is that sometimes the icons are not visible in the toolbar. Sometimes they are there, though. I could not find a proper way to reproduce the problem.

I recorded a video to demonstrate the behavior. As you can see the icons are gone until I close the app and re-open it.

[Video showing the effect of disappearing icons](https://youtu.be/cIDBwiSD3sU)

Look at the toolbar on the top right. First, there are no icons. After closing the app and re-opening it the icons are there. They also disappear randomly when I switch fragments or go to another activity and return to the fragment.

Edit: Sometimes only the search icon disappears, sometimes both icons disappear.

As mentioned it's a navigation drawer with fragments. Whenever I change the fragment from the navigation drawer the icons also have to change according to the fragment displayed.

Code-wise looks like this:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    ...

    /**
     * {@link AppCompatActivity#onCreate(Bundle)}
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Preferences.CINEMAN, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        // Compatibility with older android versions
        AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);


        // restore the saved instance state
        resolvingGoogleAPIClientError = (savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.getBoolean(STATE_RESOLVING_ERROR, false));

        fragmentStack = new HashMap<>();
        currentFragmentBackStackCount = 0;

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        decorView = this.getWindow().getDecorView();
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        profilePictureImageView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.profilePictureImageView);
        drawerHeaderMainLabel = navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.drawerHeaderMainLabel);
        drawerHeaderSubLabel = navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.drawerHeaderSubLabel);

        getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(
                () -> {
                    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                        drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
                        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(v -> onBackPressed());
                    } else {
                        drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
                        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(v -> drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START));
                    }
                    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() < currentFragmentBackStackCount) {
                        List<Fragment> fragments = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
                        for (Fragment fragment : fragments) {
                            if (fragment != null && fragment.isVisible()) {
                                activeFragment = (AppFragment) fragment;
                                updateUIForActiveFragment();
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    currentFragmentBackStackCount = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
                });

        formatNavigationDrawerElements();
    }   


    /**
     * {@link NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener#onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem)}
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_showtimes_by_movie) {
            fragmentClass = ShowtimesByMovieFragment.class;
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_showtimes_by_time) {
            fragmentClass = ShowtimesByTimeFragment.class;
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_showtimes_by_watchlist) {
            fragmentClass = ShowtimesByWatchlistFragment.class;
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_theatres) {
            fragmentClass = TheatresFragment.class;
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_articles) {
            fragmentClass = ArticlesFragment.class;
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_movies) {
            fragmentClass = MoviesFragment.class;
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_watchlist) {
            fragmentClass = MoviesWatchlistFragment.class;
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {
            fragmentClass = SettingsFragment.class;
        }

        if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
        }

        showAppFragmentOfClass(fragmentClass, false);

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Show a new app fragment of class X
     *
     * @param appFragmentClass The class of the app fragment to show
     * @param pushOnStack      Flag defining if the new fragment should be pushed on the navigation stack
     */
    void showAppFragmentOfClass(Class appFragmentClass, boolean pushOnStack, boolean isAnimatedTransition) {
        fragmentClass = appFragmentClass;
        showAppFragmentOfClass(appFragmentClass, pushOnStack, null, isAnimatedTransition);
    }

    void showAppFragmentOfClass(Class appFragmentClass, boolean pushOnStack) {
        fragmentClass = appFragmentClass;
        showAppFragmentOfClass(appFragmentClass, pushOnStack, null, false);
    }

    void showAppFragmentOfClass(Class appFragmentClass, boolean pushOnStack, AppFragment useThisInstance) {
        fragmentClass = appFragmentClass;
        showAppFragmentOfClass(appFragmentClass, pushOnStack, useThisInstance, false);
    }

    /**
     * Show a new app fragment of class X
     *
     * @param appFragmentClass The class of the app fragment to show
     * @param pushOnStack      Flag defining if the new fragment should be pushed on the navigation stack
     * @param useThisInstance  If this is set, the instance will be used and not one created
     */
    void showAppFragmentOfClass(Class appFragmentClass, boolean pushOnStack, AppFragment useThisInstance, boolean isAnimatedTransition) {
        if (!CinemanApplication.getCurrentAppInstance().isActivityVisible()) {
            return;
        }

        // do not reload the already active fragment
        if (activeFragment != null && activeFragment.getClass().equals(appFragmentClass)) {
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
            return;
        }

        try {
            if (appFragmentClass != null) {
                AppFragment fragment = null;

                if (useThisInstance != null) {
                    fragment = useThisInstance;
                } else {
                    if (fragmentStack.containsKey(appFragmentClass.toString())) {
                        fragment = fragmentStack.get(appFragmentClass.toString());
                    } else {
                        try {
                            fragment = (AppFragment) appFragmentClass.newInstance();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (fragment != null) {
                    if (!fragmentStack.containsKey(appFragmentClass.toString()) && useThisInstance == null) {
                        fragmentStack.put(appFragmentClass.toString(), fragment);
                    }

                    if (fragment.shouldBeStoredAsLastActivity()) {
                        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Preferences.CINEMAN, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                        editor.putString(Preferences.LAST_ACTIVE_FRAGMENT, appFragmentClass.toString());
                        editor.apply();
                    }

                    // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

                    if (pushOnStack) {
                        FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                        ft.addToBackStack(appFragmentClass.toString());
                        if (isAnimatedTransition) {
                            ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_out_up);
                        }
                        ft.replace(R.id.content_main, fragment, appFragmentClass.toString());
                        ft.commit();
                    } else {
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, fragment, appFragmentClass.toString()).commit();
                    }
                    fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
                    if (activeFragment != null) {
                        if (fragment.displayCloseButton()) {
                            activeFragment.doNotTrack();
                        } else {
                            activeFragment.allowTracking();
                        }
                    }
                    activeFragment = fragment;
                    updateUIForActiveFragment();
                }
            }

            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Utils.registerAppCrash(getApplicationContext());
            Utils.reportAppCrash(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@link AppCompatActivity#onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem)}
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (activeFragment != null) {
            return activeFragment.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (activeFragment != null) {
            activeFragment.setMenu(menu, getMenuInflater());
        }
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Helper method handling UI changes if the active fragment changes
     */
    private void updateUIForActiveFragment() {
        invalidateOptionsMenu();

        activeFragment.allowTracking();

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
        if (activeFragment.forcePortraitMode()) {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);
        }

        if (activeFragment.hasToolbarSpinner()) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);
            toolbarSpinner.setAdapter(buildToolbarSpinnerMenuAdapter());
            toolbarSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(activeFragment);
            toolbarSpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            toolbarSpinner.setAdapter(null);
            toolbarSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(null);
            toolbarSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            if (activeFragment.getToolbarTitle() != null) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(activeFragment.getToolbarTitle());
            }
        }

        if (activeFragment.getNavigationDrawerMenuId() >= 0) {
            if (navigationView.getMenu().findItem(activeFragment.getNavigationDrawerMenuId()).isCheckable()) {
                navigationView.getMenu().findItem(activeFragment.getNavigationDrawerMenuId()).setChecked(true);
                navigationView.setCheckedItem(activeFragment.getNavigationDrawerMenuId());
            }
        }

        setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        tabLayout.removeAllTabs();
        tabLayout.clearOnTabSelectedListeners();
        if (activeFragment.addTabs(tabLayout)) {
            tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(activeFragment);
            tabLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            tabLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        if (activeFragment.wantsFullscreenLayout()) {
            drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
            getSupportActionBar().hide();
            CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) mainContentFrame.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            mainContentFrame.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        } else {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                Window window = getWindow();
                window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
                window.setStatusBarColor(colorPrimaryDark);
            }
            drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
            getSupportActionBar().show();
            CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) mainContentFrame.getLayoutParams();
            TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
            getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.actionBarSize, typedValue, true);
            layoutParams.setMargins(0, (int) getResources().getDimension(typedValue.resourceId), 0, 0);
            mainContentFrame.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

and the fragment which is shown when selecting it in the navigation drawer:

MoviesFragment.java

```
public class MoviesFragment extends AppFragment {

    ...

    /**
     * {@link AppFragment#setMenu(Menu, MenuInflater)}
     */
    @Override
    boolean setMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater menuInflater) {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.movies_options_menu, menu);

        filterListViewMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.filter_list);
        filterListViewMenuItem.setVisible(true);

        // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchViewMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        searchViewMenuItem.setVisible(false);
        searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchViewMenuItem);
        searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(false);
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
        searchView.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.movies_search));

        updateMenu(menu);

        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void updateMenu(Menu menu) {
        BadgeStyle badgeStyle = new BadgeStyle(BadgeStyle.Style.DEFAULT, R.layout.custom_menu_action_item_badge, Color.parseColor("#ffffff"), Color.parseColor("#ffffff"), Color.parseColor("#b0152d"));
        badgeStyle.setStroke(6);
        badgeStyle.setStrokeColor(Color.parseColor("#e41e3d"));
        if (selectedMovieGenreList != null && selectedMovieGenreList.size() > 0) {
            ActionItemBadge.update(getActivity(), menu.findItem(R.id.filter_list), iconFilterList, badgeStyle, selectedMovieGenreList.size());
        } else {
            ActionItemBadge.update(getActivity(), menu.findItem(R.id.filter_list), iconFilterList, badgeStyle, null);
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@link AppFragment#onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem)}
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.filter_list:
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        openGenreFilter();
                    }
                }, 60);
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

}
```

movies_options_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/share_movie"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_share_white_24px"
        android:title="@string/movie_toolbar_share_title"
        android:visible="false"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        tools:ignore="AppCompatResource" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/movies_search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        tools:ignore="AppCompatResource" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/filter_list"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_filter"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/filter_genre_title_selector"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/custom_menu_action_item_badge"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        tools:ignore="AppCompatResource" />

</menu>
```

I do call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` when the fragment comes to the foreground so to my understanding the icons should be displayed in the toolbar.

I could not figure out what I am missing that the icons are displayed there consistently and not just randomly.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: When I do this, the problem does not seem to be happening: Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(() -> searchViewMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search), 100);

Comment: Well, instead of doing all these, you can tell activity from your fragment that fragment is going to have its own menu instead of activity by adding `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` in `onCreate` of your fragment.

Comment: Have already tried the option with setHasOptionsMenu(true); - also this didn't help. I still had situations where the icons just randomly disappeared from the actionbar.

Comment: Can you make sure `updateUIForActiveFragment` is not called multiple times in a row?

Comment: I have adjusted the method updateUIForActiveFragment() so is only called once in a row. Unfortunately this also didn't change anything about the disappearing icons.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to call the `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` inside the `onCreate()` method of the fragment since you are invalidating the options menu inside `updateUIForActiveFragment()` by calling `invalidateOptionsMenu();`

Comment: I'm already doing this in every fragment. Unfortunately this does not solve the issue.

Comment: It's really challenging. I think I can create a working example of the drawer that will change menu by fragments but I can do it at 10PM UTC as I'm still at job

Comment: any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Try to implement fragment that fragment has its own menu items.

For example:

Create one Util class and add this two method.

```
public static View addRemoveViewFromToolbar(FragmentActivity fragmentActivity, int resourceId) {
        Toolbar toolbar = removeViewFromToolbar(fragmentActivity);
        if (resourceId == 0) {
            return null;
        } else {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(fragmentActivity).inflate(resourceId, toolbar, false);
            toolbar.addView(view);
            return view;
        }
    }


    public static Toolbar removeViewFromToolbar(FragmentActivity fragmentActivity) {
        Toolbar toolbar = fragmentActivity.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        if (toolbar.getChildCount() > 1) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= toolbar.getChildCount(); i++) {//not remove navigation hamburger icon 
                toolbar.removeViewAt(1);
            }
        }
        return toolbar;
    }
```

In your fragment class:

```
View toolbarView = Util.addRemoveViewFromToolbar(getActivity(), R.layout.toolbar_filter); // create toolbar_filter xml and add search and filter images
        Imageview search = toolbarView.findViewById(R.id.img_search_view); // get widget view
```

And you should add the click or another event in this widget you want..

Comment: I don't want to use a layout file but my XML file in the menu folder. Here is how it looks:
<menu ...>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        tools:ignore="AppCompatResource" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/filter_list"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_filter"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/custom_menu_action_item_badge"
        tools:ignore="AppCompatResource" />
</menu>

Comment: Why are you not use layout file means any reason?

Comment: to my understanding best practice is to use /res/menu/some_menu.xml file where the menu items are defined. If I would use a layout xml file to apply in the toolbar this would defeat the use of the /res/menu/some_menu.xml file(s). Also I'm using the app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" function in the /menu/menu.xml file to expand/collapse the search input area inside the toolbar.

Comment: I have faced the same issue but not getting any proper solution, so that's why I am using layout file and it's work properly in my case

Comment: Ah I see. With your solution can you still use onOptionsItemSelected() or would you have to implement onClick listeners for each icon in the layout?

Comment: Implement onClick listeners for each icon in the layout

Comment: Okay it seems like this might work although it seems much more like a hack than an official solution for this problem. I wonder if this is a bug in Android...